# Win Form Colors

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

I have an access color (light yellow, or 153,255,255) but when I try to use this RGB combo in my Windows Form by using such syntax

```
System.Drawing.Color ly = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(153, 255, 255);
this.BackColor = ly;
```

the windows form does not produce the same color as my Access Form color does.  I also tried to use this

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromName("LightYellow");
```

to no such success.  Did I translate the color incorrectly?  Or can I not use the same colors?

EDIT -
@Alex K thank you for your response, I used this website to attempt to convert and that is the RGB color that it gave.  Take a look here:

http://www.numberconverter.net/get-computer-data/color-code-converter/from-rgb-to-ms-access-color/

Comment: That RGB combo is a turquoise ...  printscr the Access form, paste it into an editor and use the pipette tool to get the RGB

Comment: @AlexK. what type of editor would I use?  I was getting the forecolor of my label then using the site from my edit above to get the RGB color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access colors seems to be represented as BGR, not RGB (You can verify that quickly by inputting the values in MSPaint). You must switch the values of the first and last values.

So you will need to use

```
System.Drawing.Color ly = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 153);
```

to obtain your light yellow color.

---

If instead you want to use the literal name, you can use `FromKnownColor` which will give you an enum of all color names. It's much more error-proof.

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.LightYellow);
```

This won't restrict you on the color choice either, according to the doc `FromName` takes as an input

> Valid names are the same as the names of the elements of the
>   KnownColor enumeration.

Comment: TY!  Using the BGR combo worked!  I didn't know that it was inverted in C#.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @user2676140 `I didn't know that it was inverted in C#`. It's not. The world-wide accepted standard is RGB. If anything, Access is wrong, not C# (or rather GDI+ which is where this comes from).

Comment: Actually the bitmap format as seen on the byte level is BGRA, so Access is closer to the reality, whereas C# talks to us as if there were no absurdities at work around us all the time..

Comment: Indeed, Access is clearly inverted. C# is using the correct and usual RGB form.

Comment: @TaW - BGRA is still odd. If the Alpha channel is included, then it is almost always treated as ARGB.

Comment: In the end it probably depends on whether one accesses the bytes (BGRA) or int32 (ARGB, due to the old BigEndian madness)